# Cannot install numpy package to pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pip

My setup tools version in python is 28.8.0. 
And the pip version is 9.0.1 
I am not allowed to install packages, and I get this error message:

> Collecting numpy
>   Using cached numpy-1.12.1.zip
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "C:\Users\udari\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\setup.py", line 34, in raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
>   RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.

---

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\udari\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\ "

How can I stop this error message and install packages?

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: python version is 3.3.3

Comment: its just happening with numPy or other packages as well

Comment: Some other packages also cannot install

Comment: error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty<-This message also shown

Comment: This is the first time of installing packages to pycharm IDE

Comment: change your python interpreters to a upgraded version of python. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to look into the `setup.py` from source code of your numpy version on github here:-
[github source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.1/setup.py/%22github%20source%22)

`setup.py` **have following code that causing this error because the numpy module you are using is not compatible with the python version you have installed.**

```
if sys.version_info[:2] < (2, 7) or (3, 0) <= sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 4):
    raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
```

You should upgrade your python or downgrade numpy to 11 major version

Comment: Can you please mention the SDK version which is support for the numpy package

Comment: @Chathu greater than > 3.4 python will work, also if it helps please mark this as answer

Comment: Thank u Sharma.I uninstalled my python version 3.3.3 and installed 3.6.3.Then numpy pakcage is installed successfully.